# when on video call add feature to maximize my video when i tap on my video while calling in android mobile app

Tags: android, skype

when on video call add feature to maximize my video when I tap on my video while calling in android mobile app

there is no way to expand the my video while calling in the android app.

when on video call add feature to maximize my video when I tap on my video while calling in android mobile app

there is no way to expand the my video while calling in the android app.

when on video call add feature to maximize my video when I tap on my video while calling in android mobile app

there is no way to expand the my video while calling in the android app.